# Change structure contents by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, offset

I have a structure as follows

```
typedef struct runData{
   byte                 curentCycle = 0;
   sensorData           sensor[8];
}
```

where sensorData is the following structure

```
    typedef struct sensorData{
    float currentValue=NULL;
    float lastValue;
    float maxValue[2] = {-50 ,-50};
    float minValue [2]= {1001,1001};
    byte trend=0;               
    byte mode = 1;              
    sensorSetPoints setPoints[2];   
};
```

and sensorSetPoints is

```
typedef struct sensorSetPoints{
  float setPoint;                   
  float rise;                       
  float drop;
};
```

I create and add data by

```
runData     *thisRun;
thisRun->sensor[0].setPoints[0].setPoint = 26.77;
```

Now I want to get this value, not using the structure but by an offset pointer. I get the address of thisRun and add an offset to it, this offset comes from an array I have created on the principle that this is the 11th item in the structure and the 10 items before it (6 floats and 4 bytes) give the offset of 28. When I add this to the address of thisRun I reckon I should have a pointer pointing to thisRun->sensor[0].setPoints[0].setPoint

So if you agree with me so far why does the following not work

```
uint16_t *baseAddress = (uint16_t *)thisRun;
uint16_t offset = readOffset(10);//returns offset
baseAddress += offset;
float *f;
memcpy(f,baseAddress,4);
```

When I print f it is 0.00
What am I missing?

Comment: Is your code compiliing? How are you initializing the structure members in it's definition? Is this c++?

Comment: Why are you using `typedef` on all your `struct`s? You never specified a new type name.

Answer (score 1):

Among many problems in the code you posted, this is the most severe one

```
float *f;
memcpy(f, baseAddress, 4);
```

you are trying to write to an unallocated pointer.

You didn't even initialize `f`, depending on what you want it might be

```
float *f;
f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
if (f != NULL)
    memcpy(f, baseAddress, sizeof(*f));
```

or may be

```
float f;
memcpy(&f, baseAddress, sizeof(*f));
```

Comment: Same problem with `thisRun`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Right, I didn't see that one.

Comment: thisRun is a 214 item structure which is initialised else where and passed to this class as a pointer

Comment: There is no class involved. You are a java programmer obviously, unless you really need to don't switch from java to c or c++.

Comment: Of course an unallocated pointer f
Thought that was the problem however f still contains 0.00 and thisRun->sensor[0].setPoints[0].setPoint contains 26.77

Comment: No nothing to with java, this is only a part of a function in a class for code to run on 2 AVR's. I have not shown any of the class as it is irrelevant. The first 4 post are not actual code but just an quick example of the data layout

Answer (score 0):

Ok in case it helps someone else here is what I wanted to do, the key to it working is to use reinterpret_cast

```
intptr_t p =(intptr_t)&thisRun;  //Integer type capable of holding object pointer
p += readOffset(10);  //function which determines the offset of, in this case the 10th item
float fval = *reinterpret_cast<float *>(p);//Cast the int back to a pointer
```

Comment: Why are you using `reinterpret_cast` in C? Or did you tag your question wrong? C is not C++.